# how can an egg be balanced on a nailhead on equator

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity

How can an egg be balanced on a nail head on equator? Why only on equator and not on different latitudes?

Comment: It's not hard to balance an egg (not on a nail head), actually. And even if you did specify which equilibrium you wanted, you can still reach it (in theory, or with active balancing). The location doesn't matter - it's hard everywhere.

Comment: first you said "It's not hard", then you said "it's hard everywhere"

Comment: I don't understand this question. What makes you say it can only be balanced on the equator? Balance simply requires a configuration in which (very) small deviations from the equilibrium result in a restoring force - in other words, a system is "balanced" if there is a local energy minimum. What makes you say this can be done at the equator and not elsewhere? Sources.... context?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egg_balancing

Comment: If you read that wiki article, the very *introduction* says that it's a myth.

Comment: Is there an "urban legend" tag?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> **How can an egg be balanced on a nail head on equator?**

The same way you would balance an egg on a nail head elsewhere.

You need to ensure that the nailhead is level, that the egg's centre of gravity is over the nailhead (and ideally, over it's centre) and that the eggs surface at the point of contact is perpendicular to the line from centre-of-gravity to contact point.

> **Why only on equator and not on different latitudes?**

No reason. Perhaps someone thinks that differences in something like the Coriolis effect would be significant.

> **http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Egg_balancing**

I can find no mention of equator there.